# Symfony 6 Ajax?

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a project with Symfony 6.3.4, PHP 8.2.9, in development with a SSL certificate locally installed with symfony-cli with Windows 10 and Firefox.

In a form, I have to choose a city from a select list and then populate a second select with places located in the chosen city. Cities and places are distinct entities. I have made an Ajax fetch request to a controller method. The url for the fetch is defined with a JS const in the twig file, and the ajax request is located in a separate JS file (in public/js/ directory). The generated url is OK.

When I choose a city, the ajax request is runned but it produces a 404 error and the profiler sasys there is no entity object defined (teh entity whis associated with the controller). What is wrong? I have to use form events in complement or not ? Thanks in advance for your help.

The JS tag code for defining the route constant in the twig file :

```
<script>
    const routeLieuxVille = "{{ url('app_lieux_ville') }}";
    // generate the url 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/ville/lieux-par-ville'
</script>
```

The JS code :

```
let oCity  = document.getElementById("sortie_ville");
oCity.addEventListener("change", getPlaces);

function getPlaces() {
    // Route is defined in the template file with a js constant variable
    fetch(routeLieuxVille,
        {
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: "POST",
            mode: "same-origin",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: JSON.stringify({ "ville_id": oVille.value })
        }
    )
    .then((response) => {
         if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.status);
            }

            return response.json();
      })
      .then(
            (body) => {
                console.log('TODO : places list');
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (e) => {
                console.log(e.toString());
                alert('Une erreur est survenue.');
            }               
        );
```

The controller method which is called by the Ajax request :

```
#[Route('/places-by-city', name: 'app_lieux_par_ville')]
public function placesByCity(Request $request, PlaceRepository $placeRepository): Response
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        dump($request->request->get('villeId'));
        return new Response("it works!");
    }
    else {
        return new Response("does not macth the isXmlHttpRequest() test");
    }
}
```

The response (in the Symfony profiler via xhr response in browser inspector) :

```
"App\Entity\Ville" object not found by "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver".
```

Exception

Comment: Have you verified if you have good route?

php bin/console router:match /ville/places-by-city 
(I'm not sure if this is your path)

You can try add parameter priority: 1 (or higher)